# If $n$ is negative then for what real values of $k$ is $n^k$ real?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, real-numbers

I want to know for what real values of $k$ is $n^k$ real if $n$ is negative ?
If we assume $k$ to be rational number then we can write $k=\frac{p}{q} $ where $p,q∈Z,(p,q)=1$
If $n^k$ is real (say =$r$) then $n^p=r^q$,  if $q$ is even then $p$ should be even this contradicts $(p,q)=1$. So $q$ is odd.
It is easy to check that real rational solutions for $k$ are $k=${$\frac{p}{q}:p,q∈Z,(p,q)=1,$  $q~is~odd$}

How to approach if $k$ is irrational?
$n^\frac{1}{3}$ means to find a number when multiplied three times  by itself it gives $n$. How can we use the same of reasoning to define $~n^{\sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: " How can we use the same of reasoning to define  n2√?"  We can't.  If $n$ is negative then $n^k$ is only defined for rational numbers that have odd denominators when expressed in lowest terms.... At least when we concern ourselves with real analysis.  In complex analysis we have other definitions.  But $(-3)^{\sqrt 2}$ need not have a single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$(-1)^k=e^{(i(2n+1)\pi k)}=\cos{k(2n+1)\pi}+i \sin{k(2n+1)\pi}$$ where $n$ is an integer.

Hence the quantity in question can be real only when $\sin{k(2n+1)\pi}=0$, which means for $k(2n+1)\pi=m\pi$ or $k=\frac {m}{2n+1}$ only, where both $m,n$ are integers.

Since $n^k=(-1)^k |n|^k$, and $|n|^k$ is always real, this is the required condition.

To address the second part of your query, no, it does not make sense to define $n^{\sqrt 2}$ in the same way as we'd define, say, $n^2$. Instead, we should define it as follows:
Consider a function $f: (0,\infty) \to R$ such that $f(1)=n$ and $f'(x)$ is proportional to $f(x)$. Then, for such a function, $f(\sqrt 2)=n^{\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: I like your analysis, but (still) ask you to consider:  given the tag of (*algebra-precalculus*), do you think that it is appropriate to involve Complex Numbers / Complex Analysis in your answer?   On the other hand, the OP *accepted* your answer, so *what do I know*?

Comment: Well, I'd argue that a tag is used to represent the topic of a question. It does not necessarily mean that all answers must be confined to the subject-matter of the tag. The forum would miss out on countless novel, interesting and clever approaches to problems if it were so.

Comment: Besides, how can a discussion of when a quantity is real, occur without complex analysis? Perhaps you can help me with that.

Comment: I consider your rebuttal very reasonable.  What this means is that if the OP can not comprehend Complex Numbers or Complex Analysis, then the discussion is more challenging, but still do-able.  For this particular problem, a starting point would be [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation).  Normally, the *algebra-precalculus* flag gives fair warning that (often) the OP has not begun studying Real Analysis/Calculus, let alone Complex Analysis / Complex Numbers.  ...see next comment

Comment: Personally, I would have handled the situation as follows:  First, I would have have indicated that the discussion of $a^b$ will be confined to $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$, given the *algebra-precalculus* tag.  Then, the OP may (if he wishes) ask that the discussion be expanded to include either $a$ or $b$ in $\Bbb{C}.$  Then, I would have examined what happens when $a = 0.$  Then, I would have examined what happens when $a > 0$ and $b$ is either an integer (plus or minus or 0), a rational number, or an irrational number.  ...see next comment

Comment: So, I would have tried to explain what $(\sqrt{2})^{(\sqrt{2})}$ signifies.  Then, I would have moved on to the assumption of $a < 0$.  Here, I would have tried to examine, case by case, for what values of $b$, the expression $a^b$ will be well defined, within the Real Numbers, and for which values of $b$, the expression $a^b$ is necessarily construed to be *undefined*, within the realm of Real Numbers.  This will teach the OP that just because $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$, does not imply that $a^b$ is a well defined value in $\Bbb{R}.$  I think this captures the essence of what the OP is asking.

Comment: However, as I said, the OP accepted your answer, so *what do I know*?

Comment: Also, per your comment: "The forum would miss out on countless novel, interesting and clever approaches to problems if it were so]" : Here, I favor a different priority.  I favor ensuring that the analysis (long-winded or not) is crystal clear to the OP, with elegance/brevity of only secondary importance.